# How can I vote for an answer to a reply comment?

Tags: support, answers

Someone answered right to my question, but since he only replied to my question and didn't open a new answer, I can't mark this reply comment as the answer to the topic.

What should I do in that case? Just leave it like that? Reply with a quote to his answer (but in that case I'll get the credit and not him)?

Answer (score 4):

Leave a comment like:

> @username  That answered my question.  Please post it as an answer so I can accept.

If they don't do so after a day or two, feel free to self-answer, quoting (and attributing) their comment.

If you don't feel right about earning reputation from someone else's answer, you can mark your answer as "community wiki" by clicking the checkbox when composing it.

Comment: I just wanted to say that it's actually really good idea, since the user might not be greedy for the credit and I think it's really nice act to let him know that you appreciate his efforts and answer. btw it's really good option for those who have less than 100 reputations because they can't use the Community Wiki.